# How to override the jsessionid cookie value using java

Tags: java

In my application I want to update the `jsessionid` value from `sessionid` to **quit** or `null`. I'm performing following actions to do this thing but it is not working fine.

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("JSESSIONID","quit");
cookie.setDomain(domain);
cookie.setPath("/"+path);
cookie.setMaxAge(0);
reponse.addCookie(cookie);
```

and tried with set-cookie in headers also. I'm not able to change the cookie value. Temporarily, I am overriding with javascript, but it won't work if we enable cookie as httpOnly; and one question am I able to change the value of jsessionid if it is marked as secure.

I have multiple applications so multiple jsessionids are creating I tried to set/update those values by adding above code in response to update.

When I observed in Firefox the `jsessionid` is still there and continuing for next request cycle also. How can I change the `jsessionid` value through java. I can update with javascript but the cookies are enabled with HttpOnly flag to true.

Comment: Off topic, but use `request.getSession(false).invalidate()` to destroy the session.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?